# Run a function returning a set on a set, and get back a larger set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, list-comprehension

We can use list comprehensions on a list, and get back a list of each element run through a function. We can do the same thing with a set.

I'm looking to run each element of a set through a function, that could return another set, larger than the original input. Is this possible with comprehensions?

I could do something like this, but is there a one-liner for it?

```
ret = set()
q = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
def doubleIt( t ):
    return { t, t**2 }

for w in q:
    ret.update( doubleIt( w ) )

ret
>> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 16 }
```

The returning function will be much more complex, and could possibly return a set of sets, which I'll have to reduce further, so a one-liner would be very useful.

EDIT: Note that the returning function might also return a set. See in the example that running `2` through the function returns `{2, 4}` and running `4` through it returns `{4, 16}`, yet `4` only appears in the desired output once.

Comment: Is `q` a list? I thought lists are created with []?

Comment: `q` is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Yes lists are made with `[]`, but I'm working with sets in this case

Comment: I would ask why the DV, but that never goes anywhere...

Comment: Could you specify the "might also return a set" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two expressions yet, it's a one-liner which is not long:

```
q = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } # given
def f(x):
    return x * x
ret = q | set(f(x) for x in q)
```

In case `f(x)` returns a set:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, map(lambda a: f(a), q))
```

Comment: While this might replicate my example function, as I mentioned, the function I'm wanting to run a set through will be much more complex, and not so easily broken into a simple OR

Comment: @CDspace in that case, assuming `f()` is your function: `ret = set(f(x) for x in q)`

Comment: can the set constructor take an argument like that? the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) are woefully lacking. If so that is the answer I needed, if you want to update

Comment: You could skip the first set creation: `q | {element**2 for element in q}`

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek you're right! answer updated, thanks!

Comment: or use the explicit version `.Union()` which takes any iterator to merge into the set- a long as the function is delivering that... see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union - the shorthand `|` needs two sets.

Comment: @CDspace `set(f(x) for x in q)` isn't specific to sets. It uses generator syntax, which essentially passes a sequence into the set constructor.

Comment: `set.Union( any iterator)` vs  `set | set`

Comment: Will this work when the function is returning another set? See edits

Answer (score 2):

Using `set.union` + `reduce` + `map`

```
In [27]: reduce(set.union,map(doubleIt,q))
Out[27]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 16}
```

Just apply map function will apply the function into all elements and that will return a list of set. Then combine the set.

Comment: Combining `reduce` and `union` this way takes quadratic time, though, because it has to build a whole new set for each `union` call.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short way to do it without comprehensions:

```
set().union(*map(doubleIt, q))
```

It calls `doubleIt` on every element of `q` and merges the resulting sets into one set with [`set().union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union).

If you want a comprehension, use a set comprehension with two `for` clauses:

```
ret = {new_elem for elem in q for new_elem in doubleIt(elem)}
```

This iterates over `q`, calls `doubleIt` on each element, and iterates over the sets returned by `doubleIt`, putting the *elements* of those sets in the new set. It's equivalent to

```
ret = set()
for elem in q:
    for new_elem in doubleIt(elem):
        ret.add(new_elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner solution:

```
z=set(map(lambda x:x**2,q)).union(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best one-liner, IMO is this:

```
q = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
l = set(elem **2 for elem in q).union(q)
```